# удалять/добавлять объекты в массив

Tags: java

Добрый день!
У меня нет большого опыта, только учусь, помогите пожалуйста в таким вопросом, необходимо сделать небольшую игру, как по щелчку мыши в случае если один шарик находится внутри другого он исчезал из массива, и когда массив пустой они заново появлялись сверху и начинали падать вниз экрана, для одного шарика работает нормально, но для нескольких не хочет.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

   Ball ball;
   Aim aim;

   int livesLost = 0;             
   int score = 0;                 
   int livesPerGame = 0;
   int numberOfGames = 0;      
   int numberOfGamesPlayed = 0;
   int numOfBalls = 0;

   Ball balls[];

   void setup()
   {
   size(400,400);
   noCursor();

   ball = new Ball(40.0);
   aim = new Aim(20.0);
   livesPerGame = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Welcome to the 
   hit the ball game\nPlease enter the number of desired lives in each game: 
   ","2"));
   numberOfGames = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter 
   the number of games you would like to play: ","2"));
   numOfBalls = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the 
   maximum number of balls on the screen: ","2"));

   balls = new Ball[numOfBalls];
   for(int i = balls.length-1; i >=0; i--){
   balls[i] = new Ball(ball.getDiameter());   
   }}

   void draw(){
   background(100);

   for (int i=balls.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
   balls[i].display();
   balls[i].update();
   }


   if (ball.update() == true){
   livesLost++;
   println("Lives lost:  "  + livesLost);
   }


   if (livesLost < livesPerGame) 
   { 
   ball.display();       
   }

   else{
   numberOfGamesPlayed++;        
   if (numberOfGamesPlayed < numberOfGames){
   resetGame();
   }
   else
   tournamentOver();
   }     
   aim.display();
   aim.update();
   }

   boolean contains(){
   float d = dist(aim.getXCoord(), aim.getYCoord(), ball.getXCoord(), 
   ball.getYCoord());
   if (d <= ball.getDiameter()/2){
   return true; } 
   else {
   return false;
   }
   }

   void mousePressed (){

   if ((mousePressed == true) && (contains() == true))
   {
   ball.strike();
   score++; 
   println("Score:  "  + score);
   }
   }

   void resetGame()
   {
   println("Game Over!");
   println("Starting a new game");
   livesLost = 0;          
   score = 0;                 
   }

   void tournamentOver()
   {
   println("Game Over!");
   println("Tournament Over!");
   exit();  
   }


   public class Aim
   {
   private int xCoord;
   private int yCoord;
   private float diameter; 

   public Aim(float diameter)
   {
   setDiameter(diameter);
   }
   public void update()
   {
   xCoord = mouseX;
   yCoord = mouseY;
   }
   public void display()
   {
   fill(255,0,0);
   noStroke();
   ellipse(xCoord, yCoord, diameter, diameter);
   }

   public float getXCoord()
   {  
   return xCoord;
   }  

   public float getYCoord()
   {
   return yCoord;
   }

   public float getDiameter()
   {
   return diameter;
   }

   public void setDiameter(float diameter)
   {
   if (diameter >= 20){
   this.diameter = diameter;
   }
   else {
   this.diameter = 20;
   }
   }
   }

   boolean lifeLost = false;

   public class Ball
   {
   private float xCoord;     
   private float yCoord;     
   private float diameter;   
   private float speedY;     

   public Ball(float diameter)
   {
   setDiameter(diameter);
   resetBall();  }

   public boolean update()
   {
   yCoord = yCoord + speedY;
   if (yCoord > height + diameter/2){
   resetBall();
   lifeLost = true;
   }
   return lifeLost;
   }       

   public void display()
   {
   fill(255);
   noStroke();
   ellipse(xCoord, yCoord, diameter, diameter);
   }
   public void strike()
   {
   resetBall();
   }

   public float getXCoord()
   {  
   return xCoord;
   }  

   public float getYCoord()
   {
   return yCoord;
   }  

   public float getDiameter()
   {
   return diameter;
   }  

   public void setDiameter(float diameter)
   {
   if (diameter >= 40){
   this.diameter = diameter;
   }
   else {
   this.diameter = 40;
   }
   }

   private void resetBall()
   {
   xCoord = random(diameter/2, width - diameter/2);
   yCoord = 0;
   speedY = random(1, 2);
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

Используй **ArrayList**! Массивы не динамичные и во время работы программы его длину уже менять нельзя.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста исправить код, не совсем понимаю как его исправить. спасибо.

Comment: @Виталий Это полный листинг программы? Если нет, то выложи полностью всю программу

Comment: Сергей, это весь листинг программы.
Есть еще два класса, для создания дух шариков Ball и Aim.
Проблема что без массива программа работает нормально.
Я хотел немного усложнить и добавить массив, но при добавлении массива я не могу шариком из класса Aim и при нажатии мышки убрать их из массива.
И при давлении всех шариков класса Ball из массива, чтоб они снова появлялись вверху экрана.
за каждый шарик я получаю 1 очко, если шарик коснулся нижней границы экрана - потерял одну жизнь.
Спасибо.

Comment: @Виталий скинь пожалуйста всю программу целиком

Comment: Сергей, я скинул всю программу.
Проблема только с массивом, мне не нужно использовать ArrayList для этого задания.
спасибо!

Comment: @Виталий ну и зря. тогда думаю решайте сами вашу проблему

Comment: я не совсем понял что зря?) я вчера скинул всю программу, в т.ч. и классы, как меня попросил Сергей. –